# More call to mersenne_twister than there suppose to be

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a peculiar problem with my current code. I'm writing a program that needs to generate random real number from two distributions (a normal distribution and a real one.) The code to generate these values live inside a for loop :

```
    char* buffer = new char[config.number_of_value * config.sizeof_line()];

    //...

    //Loop over how much values we want
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < config.number_of_value; ++i)
    {
        //Calculates the offset where the current line begins (0, sizeof_line * 1, sizeof_line * 2, etc.)
        std::size_t line_offset = config.sizeof_line() * i;

        //The actual numbers we want to output to the file
        double x = next_uniform_real();
        double y = config.y_intercept + config.slope * x + next_normal_real();

        //Res is the number of character written. The character at buffer[res] is '\0', so we need
        //To get rid of it
        int res = sprintf((buffer + line_offset), "%f", x);
        buffer[line_offset + res] = '0';

        //Since we written double_rep_size character, we put the delimiter at double_rep_size index
        res = sprintf((buffer + line_offset + config.data_point_character_size() + sizeof(char)), "%f", y);
        buffer[line_offset + config.data_point_character_size() + sizeof(char) + res] = '0';
    }

    return buffer;
```

When running the program the usual value of "number_of_value" is 100'000. So there should be 100'000 calls to next_uniform_real() et 100'000 calls next_normal_real(). The strange parts is, when I profile this code with VSPerf on Visual Studio 2017 I get 227'242 calls to the mersenne_twister generator, which is 113'621 calls to each functions. As you can see there is 3'621 calls more than there is suppose to be.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

For reference, the functions look like this :

```
double generator::next_uniform_real()
{
    return uniform_real_dist(eng);
}

double generator::next_normal_real()
{
    return normal_dist(eng);
}
```

Where eng is std::mt19937, seeded with a random_device or time(0) when random_device has no entropy.
normal_dist is of type std::normal_real_distribution<> 
and uniform_real_dist is of type std::uniform_real_distribution<>

For those wondering, I'm filling up a buffer a char* so that I can make one single write to an ostream rather than one for each iteration of the loop.

(As an aside, if someone knows a faster way to write float/double values to char* or a faster way to generate real numbers than this method, that'd be really helpful!)

Comment: How does it behave with `number_of_value` being 1, 10, 100?

Comment: It is odd to write `sizeof(char)`. The standard defines it always equal to `1`.

Comment: @Angew with `number_of_value` I have 476 calls to generate_canonical

Comment: @S.M. I know, but I thought it would be more readable and understandable if I explicity stated I add the size of one character rather than an arbitrary '1'

Comment: You are wrong supposing that `sizeof(char)` is more clear than `1`. Yet another thought, what does happen with your code if you decide to replace char with wide char in your code?

Comment: Could you expand on why you think `sizeof(char)` is clearer than `1`? As for your second point, the only char I use are `,` for the delimiter and `\n` so I don't plan on using wide char. But maybe I should. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: What are your call counts to `next_uniform_real` and `next_normal_real`?

Comment: I believe they've been optimized away since I don't see them in the profiler

Comment: When I need a real fast RNG not bothered with crypto-security, I use one created by George Marsaglia, called  "very long period (2^60) random number generator".  I also use his "Monte Python" algorithm for normal distribution.  Alas, the citations in my code are all dead links.

Comment: @JiveDadson I'll look into this, thanks

Comment: Also take a look at the cheaper generators in stl, like linear_congruential

Comment: I have a distribution engine for normal_distribution that is 3 1/2 times faster than the one that comes in the box with VC++17.  I'm trying to figure out a way to fit it into the SO rules of engagement.

Comment: @JiveDadson do you have a github link?

Comment: I created one. Don't say I never did anything nice for you. https://github.com/JiveDadson/MontyPythonRNG

Comment: @JiveDadson if this wasn't the internet I'd pay you a beer

Comment: I have paypal. :-) I am trying to figure out how to remove numeric.h. You don't need it.

Comment: If it's only a git problem, do git rm numerics.h

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine if you're trying to generate a random integer between 1 and 10 inclusive and your input source provides a random number between 1 and 12 inclusive. If you get a number between 1 and 10, you can just output it. But if you get an 11, you must get another number between 1 and 12. So extra calls may be needed when matching a random source to a random output with a different distribution.

Comment: I see... Is there a way to reduce this phenomenon?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: Well, currently, the random generation is the bottleneck of my data generation. Ultimately I would like this use a faster generator (currently surfing the web for an answer). In the meantime, if this would to happen less often, there would be less call to canonical_generate, right?

Comment: What are you requirements? What threats do you need to protect against? A Mersenne twister might be overkill.

Comment: My only requirement is to generate float or double numbers with an arbitrary precision, and to do so fast. I'm not sure I understand your question about threats though. What would suggest instead of a Mersenne twister?

Comment: @DatCorno A "threat" would be something like "I need to make sure an attacker who observes millions of consecutive outputs from my random number generator can't make any predictions about the next outputs that are correct more often than chance". If you have minimal requirements and no threats, you can use a much faster PRNG (like PCG or Xorshift or many others).

Comment: I'll look into them, I appreciate your input!

Answer (score 6):

All major standard library implementations of `std::normal_distribution` use the [Marsaglia polar method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsaglia_polar_method). As noted in the Wikipedia article,

> this procedure requires about 27% more evaluations of the underlying random number generator (only π/4 ≈ 79% of generated points lie inside of unit circle).

Your number sounds about right (100000 uniform reals at 1 RNG call per number plus 100000 normal reals at 1.27 RNG calls per number is 227000).

Comment: I've read a paper on the Ziggurat method, would this speed up the process or just lower the amount of calls required?

Comment: @DatComo Ziggurat uses data tables. On a modern machine, that can be death to throughput. Only way to tell would be to try it.